# Next Approver Role in NetSuite WorkFlow

Tags: netsuite

I am creating a Workflow, and I need to set Next Approver Role… but can’t find the setting. I only see “Next Approver”, but not “Next Approver Role”… Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

On the workflow set the next approver and on the same action you can add the condition where you can mention the user role. Please see the image for your reference : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckF0T.png)